# Getting writeToFile:atomically: URL saved to

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm saving some `NSData` with `writeToFile:atomically:` and then want to use that file very shortly afterwards. What is the easiest way to get the `NSURL` of the file I just saved?

Answer (score 2):

[`[NSData writeToFile: atomically:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile%3aatomically%3a) has a path parameter.

Just make the path parameter into a file URL and save that as an instance variable or property and you'll be all set.

Or even better, use [`[NSData writeToURL: atomically:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToURL%3aatomically%3a) (i.e. convert your path into a URL to start with) and save *that* as a property or instance variable to be used later on.

You can convert a path into a file URL via [`[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/initFileURLWithPath%3a).

And lastly, the *real* answer to the question you're trying to ask is:  no, you can not divine the path or URL from an arbitrary "`NSData`" object.  You'll have to save that information separately or alongside your data in order to keep track of where it came from.

Comment: +1, plus want to point out the convenience constructor `+[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`.